# What happens to a pointer referenced by a closure that is effectively let go?

Tags: swift

The following is pseudo-code to help demonstrate my question:

```
var dataSourceArray = [CustomClassObject]()

databaseListener { (data) in
    dataSourceArray.removeAll()

    let id = data.id
    let imageURL = data.imageURL
    let listing = CustomClassObject(id: id, image: nil)

    remoteFileStorage.getImage(url: imageURL) { (image) in
        listing.image = image
    }

    dataSourceArray.append(listing)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

`databaseListener` is a realtime database listener that can return updates rapidly. In its completion handler is an async call that downloads an image. If `databaseListener` returns new data before `remoteFileStorage` has a chance to return from the last run, what happens to the `listing` pointer in the `remoteFileStorage` closure? The `listing` pointer no longer has a home in `dataSourceArray` (it was just purged) so can the `remoteFileStorage` handler safely access it anyway? My assumption is that the `listing` pointer is still pointing to a valid address in memory since the `remoteFileStorage` closure has a reference to it, but I am not certain?

Comment: In short, simple reference semantics are unlikely to cause the problem you describe. What can cause problems, though, is any unsynchronized mutation of this array. Is it possible that you’re mutating it while accessing it from another thread? In short, on what queues are these `databaseListener` and `removeFileStorage` calling their respective completion handlers? I might suggest turning on the thread sanitizer (on your scheme’s “run” setting, under “diagnostics”) just to make sure everything is copacetic.

Comment: If that doesn’t identify the issue, instead of pseudocode, I’d suggest you edit the question to include an actual [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that manifests the problem. So, create blank project and add just enough to manifest the bug in question. Looking at pseudo-code, we can only guess. If you can provide actual simplified code that will reliably manifest the problem, then we’re more likely to be able to help.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the reply, I just want to say what an asset you are to this community. My question is more of a hypothetical one. I'm scripting this right now and the thought dawned on me. What happens to the `listing` pointer that's referenced by the `remoteFileStorage` completion handler when the array that it's in is purged?

Comment: @Rob Is it the case that after the array is purged, the `listing` only exists in the scope of the `remoteFileStorage` handler and assigning it an image will safely assign it an image (since it still exists, however futile since it will never be rendered on screen) but when the completion handler finishes, the `listing` is deallocated by ARC since it has nothing else referencing it?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. In the absence of some qualifier, ARC will keep strong reference until closure finishes. Or you might consider using `[weak listing]` and `listing?.image = image` if you don’t want it to persist beyond its useful life. But either way, that won’t be source of “bad access” errors. My bet would be some non-thread-safe code, but we’re just guessing in the absence of MCVE.